# Eclipse running previous version of plugin project or not seeing changes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

For example:
I create Hello, World Command project (*File>New>Others...>Plug-in Development>Plug-in Project>Hello, World template*) and Run it as Eclipse application: [image]

Next, I change name's value in command (*line 12* in *plugin.xml*) to "HelpMe" and runs it again as Eclipse application, **but as a result I am getting exactly the same app.**

After that I change (*line 14*) id from `example.commands.sampleCommand` to `example.commands.foo` (and obviously change it in other places, where it' s used) and runs it:
[image]

Now it worked !

plugin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            name="Sample Category"
            id="example.commands.category">
      </category>
      <command
            name="Sample Command"
            categoryId="example.commands.category"
            id="example.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            commandId="example.commands.sampleCommand"
            class="example.handlers.SampleHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="example.commands.sampleCommand"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            sequence="M1+6"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="Sample Menu"
               mnemonic="M"
               id="example.menus.sampleMenu">
            <command
                  commandId="example.commands.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S"
                  id="example.menus.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar
               id="example.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
            <command
                  commandId="example.commands.sampleCommand"
                  icon="icons/sample.gif"
                  tooltip="Say hello world"
                  id="example.toolbars.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

So why does it helps, if id's value shouldnt' matter ?

Also, note that this is just an example, but I met up with very similar issues, like: eclipse was launching old plugin which wasn' t even in workspace anymore; or launched previous version of project.
It is a bug or matter of configurations ?

I am using Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Comment: Make sure you have '-clean' in the Program Arguments in the Run Configuration for the Eclipse Application that you run when testing.

Comment: Thanks, it helped +1